# Value of expression with pre-increment and post-decrement in Java

Tags: java, associativity

Consider the following expressions:

```
int x = 5, y = 5, z;
z = y + x * y-- + ++x;
```

According to my calculations the value of z should be 40 considering `++` and `--` have higher precedence than `+`.

So `z = 4 + 6 * 5 + 6 = 40`.

Running the code yields a result of `z = 36`. How does Java arrive at that result?
Also, what role does associativity (right to left) play here?

Answer (score 3):

You must interpret it from left to right, so :

so `z = y(5) + x(5) * y--(still 5, since the decrement will apply afterwards) + ++x(which is 6 because the increment applies before the evaluation of x)`

The result being `36`.

Comment: pre/post increment/decrement Operators have higher precedence than arithmetic operators.. so why evaluate from left to right?

Comment: Operator *precedence* tells you how to *parse* the grammar - what the AST looks like if you will, or how implicit braces are set. It says nothing about *evaluation order*, which is left-to-right in the parse tree, with post- operator applied before the evaluation and pre- operators applied before the evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

Operator *precedence* tells you how to *parse* the expression. It doesn't tell you anything about *evaluation order*.

There are two ways to look at this, you can either look at it as implicit braces, or as how the AST looks like.

If you look at it through the PoV of using braces, you end up with this:

```
    z = y + x * y-- + ++x;
<=> z = y + (x * (y--)) + (++x);
<=> z = 5 + (5 * 5) + 6 // y-- is still 5 (4 afterwards), ++x is 6
<=> z = 5 + 25 + 6
<=> z = 36
```

If you look at it through the AST lens, you get

```
  +
 / \
y   +
   / \
  *   x++
 / \
x   y--
```

Now if you go through that AST in evaluation order (left-right), you see that the leftmost y is still 5. On the right tree, we have again a +, which is the result of the multiplication and ++x. The multiplication is 5 * 5, since y-- is still 5 at that point, and y is 4 afterwards. And finally, ++x is 6 and x is 6 afterwards. Putting together, 5 + 25 + 6 = 36.

The AST is always evaluated in-order, operator precedence tells you how the AST looks like (stronger binding operators at the bottom, weaker binding one at the top).

Answer (score 0):

```java
int x = 5, y = 5, z;
z = y + x * y-- + ++x;
```

In this example `var--` and `var++` will be executed *after* `z`. And `--var` and `++var` will be executed *before* `z`. In your case

```
z = 5 + 5 * 5 + 6 = 36
```

If you rewrite your expression to `z = y + x * --y + ++x` it will be `z = 5 + 5 * 4 + 6 = 40`.

If you rewrite your expression to `z = y + x * y-- + x++` it will be `z = 5 + 5 * 5 + 5 = 35`.